# Number of possibilities to play Connect Four

Tags: combinatorics

I have watched the Numberphile video *Connect Four* from Brady Haran (https://youtu.be/yDWPi1pZ0Po) where Brady presents "how many different ways can you fill the 6 x 7 grid" which is 4531985219092. However this number includes the empty board or the board where just the first disc was inserted. It does not represent the number of different ways how you can play the game until either one player wins or until it is a draw after 42 plies.

Who could help me to find this number of possible game variations?

(the links in https://oeis.org/A212693 which might give a clue are broken)

Comment: The main difficulty to determine this number is that we have to stop as soon as one side gets four in a row.

Comment: But the same difficulty arises when you count the "legal positions" as they do in https://oeis.org/A212693 (at least I assume that they must have excluded positions where one player had won in between before the last move). So the guys who found the winning strategy for Connect 4 should know the answer

Comment: Explanation of 4531985219092 was linked in the answer to [How many different game situations has connect four?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/301106/318073), linking to [John's Connect Four Playground](https://tromp.github.io/c4/c4.html) which also links to the [broken] OEIS link - but I've found an alternate source of the link here [Symbolic Classification of General Two-Player Games](https://fai.cs.uni-saarland.de/kissmann/publications/ki08-ggpsolver.pdf).

Comment: @RüdiJehn I am not sure whether all positions were verified or whether just the valuation of the first moves was completed. In fact, this is a quite dynamic task and I doubt we can do it without brute force and a computer. Similar caclulations have been done for chess.

Comment: To be clear, you are asking for the total number of ways to reach terminal states? (Total number of terminal states is 1905333170621 according to the video you linked.)

Comment: Yes. This precisely is my question. And most of the terminal states can be reached in many many different ways (assume player A puts his first 4 coins in column 1 to 4 and wins and player B puts his 3 first coins all in column 7, then we can reach this terminal state in 4! = 24 different ways, because player A could fill the first 4 columns in any order)

Comment: @Peter: Sure this needs to be done with brute force and a computer. But it might be that someone has done it already, since the game was totally analyzed.